# SpeechRecognizer not work, COMException: Class not registered/ UWP App Windows IoT (10.0.10586) and Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, speech-recognition, win-universal-app, uwp, windowsiot

After I have installed Windows IoT (10.0.10586) and Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1, I got COM-Exception when I use the SpeechRecognizer in Universal App on my Raspberry Pi 2 (with Windows IoT 10.0.10586).

If I run the SpeechRecognizer UWP App on Windows 10 it works without any problems, the COM-Exception occurs only in Windows IoT (10.0.10586). With older version of Windows IoT and Visual Studio 2015 without Update 1 it works, too.

Has anyone a solution for the problem?

```cs
var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
var constraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "dictation");
speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(constraint);
await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

//This line throw exception:
//Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in App.exe
//WinRT information: Class not registered
//Operation not supported.Unknown error: 0x80070057.
var result = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
```

To get the sample work enable the following capabilities in the Package.appxmainifest:

Internet (Client) and Microphone

**Edit**

Like Eric Brown said RecognizeWithUIAsync seems not to work with Windows IoT (I rememberd not correctly, it seems to be I never used RecognizeWithUIAsync but I know SpeechRecognizer works in past).

But RecognizeAsync does not work for me, too. No Exception is thrown, but RecognizeAsync not wait for speech, it directly returns an SpeechRecognitionResult-object where property Confidence is Rejected and Status is Success, but spoken Text is always an empty string. It works on Windows 10, but not on Windows IoT.

Has anyone an idea why no speech is detected/ the spoken words not will be returned?

```cs
var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
var constraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "dictation");
speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(constraint);
await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
while (true)
{
    var result = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text) ? result.Text : "No speech in result.");
}
```

To get the sample work enable the following capabilities in the Package.appxmainifest:

Internet (Client) and Microphone

Comment: Did you check if any languages are installed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it, yes there was en-US installed and I installed de-DE, but still not works.

Comment: What sort of microphone and audio input device do you have attached?   Can you verify that audio input works at all?

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I verified that microphone works correctly with a simple audio recorder app. Microphone is working properly, still no speech detection.

Comment: The only other thing I'd check at this point is to verify that you can access the internet.  If it still doesn't work, send me your entire project and I'll have some other team members look at it.   That won't happen until after the new year, though.

Comment: Thanks for the really nice offer and your help. It worked not with the microphone that I have, with a new SpechRecognizer in Windows IoT 10.0.10586 compatible microphone it works (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got SpeechRecognizer to work with Windows IoT 10.0.10586 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

**The solution: Use a microphone that is fully compatible with Windows IoT 10.0.10586. I use the Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 (there is a microphone included).**

SpeechRecognizer now working with ContinuousRecognitionSession and RecognizeAsync with a grammer file (file that defines what user can say) and with dictation (free speech). RecognizeWithUIAsync not work and maybe never will work (see Eric Browns answer).

Note: It is a mistake to believe that if a microphone works in any other app, it have to work with SpeechRecognizer, too. I have a microphone that works with a simple audio recorder app, but not works with the SpeechRecognizer. Note also that microphones that have worked with SpeechRecognizer in older Windows IoT versions not always have to work with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT 10.0.10586.

It is not really nice to use a webcam as microphone. If someone has a microphone that works with SpeechRecognizer and Windows IoT 10.0.10586 please post it.

If you look for a SpeechRecognizer ContinuousRecognitionSession with a grammar file example you can look in following project. In the comments you can see how you can use other languages with SpeechRecognizer.

https://www.hackster.io/krvarma/rpivoice-051857

Perhaps there is in future driver updates in Windows Updates and we no longer have such problems.

Comment: I have tested four other usb microphones. Two of them worked with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT 10.0.10568. Microphones that works: "Blue Microphones Snowball" (it is really big) and "Kinobo - Mini Akiro USB Microphone".

Comment: I can confirm that continous speech recognition works on Windows IoT 10.0.10586 with the Kinobo Microphone. A cheap buy with nice quality and range :)

Comment: Perhaps also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938495/usb-microphone-not-working-with-windows-iot-core

Answer (score 2):

`RecognizeWithUIAsync` isn't implemented in Windows IoT (because there's no UI).   You can use `RecognizeAsync` just fine.