# USB Microphone not working with Windows IOT Core

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I tried both the November 2015 release (build 10586) and the Feb 2016 Insider Preview release (build 14262), however my **USB microphone is not working with Windows 10 IOT core**.

**Scenario:**

I am creating a speech recognition based program using windows IOT Core.

I am using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition api for this job. When I run the program on a simulator in my Window 10 PC using Visual Studio 2015, microphone works and sound gets detected and the program functions as required.

However when i deploy the same build to my Raspberry Pi2, which has Window IOT Core installed, program doesnt detect any sound. I see that my microphone is detected correctly by Windows IOT Core, as i can see the same in the default app which comes with Windows IOT core.

I can listen the sounds (headphone) though. However somehow my microphone voice is not getting through to my speech recognition program when it runs on RPi2 with Windows 10 IOT Core.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a speech recognition program using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition api.
2. Check the program functioning on Windows 10 pc in a simulator
3. Deploy the same build to RPi2 with Windows 10 IOT core.
4. Program doesnt detect any sound from microphone.

Need serious help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a microphone that is fully compatible with the SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core. I have tested some microphones that works with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core.

**Microphones that works with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core Build 10586**

- Kinobo - Mini Akiro USB Microphone
- Blue Microphones Snowball (it is really big)
- Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 (it is a web cam with a microphone included)

**Microphones that works with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core Build 14295**

- Kinobo - Mini Akiro USB Microphone
- Blue Microphones Snowball (not tested but should work)
- Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 (not tested but should work)

**Microphones that works with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core Build 15063**

- Logitech G933 Artemis Spectrum Wireless Headset
- Kinobo - Mini Akiro USB Microphone (not tested but should work)
- Blue Microphones Snowball (not tested but should work)
- Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 (not tested but should work)
- Logitech G930 Wireless Headset (not tested but should work)

Please feel free to post microphones that works with SpeechRecognizer in Windows IoT Core.

Answer (score 0):

That's because

`Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer` does not support now.

you can check here
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/UnavailableApis.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar on Raspbian with a USB Mic and it works with the SpeechRecognition library that you can get through apt-get. It also requires PyAudio or PortAudio and FLAC so you might need those for the Win10 version. (I have a Kinobo Rikuto from Amazon at about £3.99)

Comment: The libraries might be the same? I don't know as I've never used IOT Core